# How to set a domain to ubuntu server 16 in VMware?

Tags: server, vmware, domain-server

I have a pc with ubuntu-desktop OS. I have installed a VMware on it.
 Then I have installed a ubuntu server in VMware. I can connect to it with  `ssh vmware-ubuntu@192.168.xxx.xxx` from my ubuntu desktop.

I wanna connect to my **ubuntu server 16 in VMware** with a domain name.

**e.g**

```
ssh vmware-ubuntu@my_domain.com
```

How can I do that?

**UPDATE 1**
I have edited `/etc/hosts` and add `192.168.xxx.xxx server.com` on it. but I can't connect with `ssh vmware-ubuntu@server.com`

Comment: You mean there is another machine in the VMnet that tries to connect your Ubuntu server that is also inside a VMnet but fails, while a physical machine is able to connect?

Comment: Yes, I wanna set a domain on my ubuntu IP on a VMware.

Comment: What is your hypervisor that is hosting your VMs? Is it VMware workstation (while both VMs on a pc), or VMWare vSphere with a virtualization server? Are both of your VMs in the same VMnet? Or do they use some sort of routing? Please **edit** your question and add this information, and overall as many details as you can regarding your environment so we can help you better.

Comment: It is VMware workstation. I have a pc with ubuntu desktop OS. I have installed a VMware on it. Then I have installed a ubuntu server in VMware. Now I wanna connect to ubuntu server in VMware from my ubuntu desktop.

Comment: That is a whole different description than what you wrote in your question. I assume you would like to connect from your desktop to the server using a name only and not an ip address. The easiest way would be editing your `/etc/hosts` file, adding your domain name alongside your server's ip address. The harder method would be to setup a dns server on your desktop or virtual server that has a dns record for your domain name, and add this server address to your dns list on your desktop.

Comment: I have edited ```/etc/hosts``` and add ```192.168.172.128 server.com``` on it. but I can connect with ```ssh vmware-ubuntu@server.com```

Comment: You mean you can't* connect? Or did it work?

Comment: I'm so sorry. It can't connect. It didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120790/discussion-between-pizza-and-hossein-safari).